# rebuild ordered list if goes wrong

Tags: mysql

I have managed to build myself a working drag and drop ordering list with JavaScript, PHP, mysql which is working well. This integrates with a category system which can multiple select different category to be displayed in the list.  For this reason I am keeping the list of entries sequential throughout all categories.

My concern is if at some point something goes wrong and the ordered list becomes out of sync, how to rebuild it to make the number values a continuous numbered ordered list again. eg: 1 -> 1000000000.

My thoughts are about any duplicate records, or missing records. When one of these errors are found; to take each entry higher than this error and rebuild a ordered list.

eg: 
a broken order list is:    1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
so to rebuild the list as: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

or: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
to: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Which will allow the ordered index to function correctly again. This query would also fix any other errors found along the way.

This is going into mysql which I haven't quite understood yet, let alone know if possible. I think this probably is, but I need some help in going in the right direction. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [DEMO:](http://rextester.com/KFPF12180)

Use a user variable to establish a Row Number (RN) on your base table and then use that RN to update the SortOrder.

If this SortOrder is by some grouping as well we would need to use a 2nd (or more) user variables to control the reset of the RN so that row numbers are partitioned by that group. Example: if each user has a sort order then we would need to reset row numbers for each user and update the below by adding a new user variable, case statement to handle reset of row number and order our subquery 1st by the user.

But in the case of a single list w/o a group the below should work.

It would be wise to have a secondary order in the subquery so that we can define in which order the rows appear when you have duplicate values (something that would make ordering unique, in this case ID would work fine); however if you don't care then it could occur in a undefined sort sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE SO46469439_Foo (
  ID int,
  Sortorder int);

INSERT INTO SO46469439_Foo (ID, Sortorder) VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,4),(5,9);

#Return dataset showing improper SortOrder
SELECT * FROM SO46469439_Foo Order by SortOrder;

#Update  dataset to have proper SortOrder no gaps no duplicates.
UPDATE SO46469439_Foo SRC 
#This inner join is so that we get a row_number for each SortOrder
#that row number is then used to update sortOrder
INNER JOIN  (SELECT A.*, @RN:=@RN+1 RN 
             FROM SO46469439_Foo A
#Cross join to initialize user variable which we use for row number
#in DBs which support analytical functiosn we would just use Row_number()
# over (partition by Groups order by Groups, sortOrder) to get a RN
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) Z
             ORDER BY SortOrder) UP
 ON SRC.ID = UP.ID
 SET SRC.SortOrder = UP.RN;

#show updated results
SELECT * FROM SO46469439_Foo order by SortOrder
```

Giving us:

```
improper SortOrder
+----+----+-----------+
|    | ID | SortOrder |
+----+----+-----------+
|  1 | 1  | 1         |
|  2 | 2  | 2         |
|  3 | 3  | 2         |
|  4 | 4  | 4         |
|  5 | 5  | 9         |
+----+----+-----------+

Proper SortOrder. Note:The duplicated 2 is gone and the 9 has been brought in.
+----+----+-----------+
|    | ID | SortOrder |
|  1 | 1  | 1         |
|  2 | 2  | 2         |
|  3 | 3  | 3         |
|  4 | 4  | 4         |
|  5 | 5  | 5         |
+----+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me this guidance. Quite a lot for me to digest there which I will look through.

Comment: Ask questions if you need help understanding; I'd rather develop a more complete answer so you learn to fish than provide an answer having fished for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to come back to you as this is something as a little project as an enhancement more than essential.